# Does the Schmidt decomposition still hold in infinite dimension?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, singular-values

The demonstration of Schmidt decomposition I know of relies on the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition). Is the usual hypothesis of separability enough to carry the concept to infinite dimensions? If so, I would appreciate a reference to consult.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/270960/84108